# Сервис прорабатывает только 1 раз

Tags: java, android, kotlin

В MainActivity я запускаю AlarmManager, который каждые 24 часа должен обращаться к моему сервису MyService при нажатии на кнопку. Я нажимаю на кнопку, проходит 24 часа, сервис срабатывает и меняет значение моего виджета. Проходит еще 24 часа - сервис не работает. Что с ним делать? Буду очень благодарен!
P.s. есть предположение, что это из-за того, что я запускаю сервис в MainActivity один раз, а после этого закрываю приложение, MainActivity соответственно тоже закрывается.

Кусок MainActivity.kt

```
private fun initFuncs() {
    startBtn.setOnClickListener {
        writeData()
        startBroadcast()

    }
    stopBtn.setOnClickListener {
        deleteData()
        stopBroadcast()
    }
}

private fun stopBroadcast() {
    stopService(Intent(this, MyService::class.java))
}

private fun startBroadcast() {
    val intent = Intent(this, MyService::class.java)
    val pendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getService(applicationContext, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
    val alarmManager = getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(
        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        System.currentTimeMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
        pendingIntent
    )
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm will ring after every 15 minutes interval", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        .show()
}
```

Кусок MyService.kt

```
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    Paper.init(this)
    Toast.makeText(this, "onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    checkData()
    pasteData()
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Comment: Взводите Alarm Manager еще раз после срабатывания - так надежнее setExact